# Recurrences of lists

Tags: equation-solving, recursion

Assume we have a multi-dimensional recurrence, e.g.

$\qquad\begin{align*}
  a_1 &= (1,2) \\
  a_n &= (1,2) + a_{n-1} \quad, n>1
\end{align*}$

with the easy solution $a_n = (n,2n)$.

How can I solve such recurrences in Mathematica? The expression

```
RSolve[{a[1] == {1, 2}, a[n] == {1, 2} + a[n - 1]}, a[n], n]
```

evaluates to

```
{}
```

in Mathematica 9.0.0.0. Naturally,

```
RSolve[{
  a1[1] == 1, a1[n] == 1 + a1[n - 1], 
  a2[1] == 2, a2[n] == 2 + a2[n - 1]
}, {a1[n], a2[n]}, n]
```

works, but this strikes me as inconvenient. Given that the translation is this immediate (provided all occurring lists have the same length) I suspect there might be a way to do it without boilerplate.

Comment: For this particular example: `RSolve[{a[1] == #, a[n] == # + a[n - 1]}, a[n], n] & /@ {1, 2}`.

Comment: @Anon Okay, replacing afterwards in the symbolic result, nice. What are the restrictions of this?

Comment: If the relations cannot be solved separately it won't work. This is equivalent to using `RSolve` two times, one for each index.

Comment: Because the dimensions may have some inter-dependence, I suspect something like `With[{rule=a[n_]:>{a[1][n], a[2][n]}},RSolve[Thread/@({a[1] == {1, 2}, a[n] == {1, 2} + a[n - 1]}/.rule),a[n]/.rule, n]]` could be used, but unfortunately I don't have Mathematica available right now so I can't test it.

Comment: @VF1 I don't understand your code but I tried it; the result is also `{}`.

Comment: @Anon But Mathematica *is* able to solve systems of mutually dependent recurrences, isn't it?

Comment: @Raphael Yes, I think so but not with the syntax you want I am afraid. What I wrote was just something that used a simple syntax, but with that comes that constraint.

Comment: @Anon I'm not too obsessed with the particular syntax (though the point of the question is to avoid as much boilerplate as possible) so I'd appreciate any answer that, well, answers the question as generally as possible.

Comment: @Raphael I think you may have answered it yourself, the "inconvenient" version might the best one can do. But keep the question open, perhaps someone will come up with something.

Comment: Raphael, I'd like to test if my approach works, but it's very hard to debug Mathematica code without the program itself. What is the result of `Thread/@({a[1] == {1, 2}, a[n] == {1, 2} + a[n - 1]}/.a[n_]:>{a[1][n], a[2][n]})` on its own? Try wrapping this expression in the `RSolve` with `Flatten` and then `Evaluate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SetAttributes[split, HoldAll];
split[var_, eqs_, dim_] := 
 Map[Thread, 
   Hold@eqs /. var[n_] :> Through[(var /@ Range[dim])[n]] // 
    ReleaseHold] // Flatten
RSolve[split[a, {a[1] == {1, 2}, a[n] == {1, 2} + a[n - 1]}, 2], 
split[a, a[n], 2], n]
(* {{a[1][n] -> n, a[2][n] -> 2 n}} *)
```

`split` should work for `Solve`-ing vector-valued functions, too.

Comment: So this essentially translates the set of equations, right? Nice. For the record (this may be obvious) this works also if the underlying recurrences are mutually dependent.

Comment: @Raphael Yes. I had to inject into the `Hold` and then release it because the problem with the code I posted as a comment was that the `Plus` was distributing the `a[n]` term before the replacement, resulting in a matrix when I split it.